# Setting minimum value to select in select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-select

Is there a way by which I can validate select two only to allow a minimum number of selection length as it has for `maximumSelectionLength`.

I have tried `minimumSelectionLength` but it does not work for me :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select2/select2.min.css" />
<script src="select2/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".selecte").select2();
      maximumSelectionLength: 15;

    });
</script>
```

So I want the button not to submit until the user selects up to like 3 items.

Any ideas or suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select2` plugin don't have any attribute for this purpose so you could validate the `select` element want in `submit` event make you condition then submit  when it's achieved :

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
     var minimum = 3;

     if($(".selecte").select2('data').length>=minimum)
         return true;
     else 
         return false;
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(".selecte").select2();

$('form').on('submit', function(){
     var minimum = 2;

     if($(".selecte").select2('data').length>=minimum){
         alert('Submited...')
         return true;
     }else {
       alert('Please shoose at least '+minimum+' item(s)')
         return false;
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select multiple class="selecte" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
  
  <br>
  
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: @KrushioVida updated my answer (including live example).

Answer (score 2):

```
    var min = 1; 
    $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
        if ($('#group_select option:selected').size() < min) {
            alert("Need at least one group");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Popup a alert if the min requirement is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Use .val() in your JS to get the value of the input, after that you can use regex in an if statement that if it returns true ( meets the value requirement set by regex ) then it will submit. You can use console.log() the value, to see what data you are working with. (regex101.com is a great place to build your regex code.)

Comment: @richard-maltbyThanks for your feedback. do you have an example of a code i try to implement